# Replace dictionary key with a property of itself

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's say I have a Dictionary defined this way:

`var Dict = Dictionary<Person, List<Car>>`

With both Person and Car being objects. If I wanted to turn that dictionary into this:

`var Dict = Dictionary<Person.Id, List<Car>>`

What process would it need to go through?

Comment: In the first code fragment you have `List<Cars>` and in your second code fragment you have `List<Car>`. Should they both be `List<Car>` or are they actually two different types?

Comment: You're trying to map the key mechanism of the dictionary object with a property of an object. That is illegal - you need to define the key with the object *type* that will be mapped to it, not a property of a type. In this case, that would be the object type that Person.Id is based on. (int, guid, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use [ToDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-6.0) method that creates another `Dictionary` by keys which you expect.

```
var result = Dict.ToDictionary(x=>x.Key.Id,z=>z.Value)
```